# Integrating to infinity in Matlab

Tags: matlab, physics, numerical-integration

I was trying to find the Steffan-Boltzmann constant by integrating from 0 to infinity the expression that gives the amount of energy emited by surface unit, E(lambda, T). How can I this numerically in Matlab? I'm having trouble with the loop that would give me the integral.

```
h = 6.626e-34; 
c = 2.998e8;
k = 1.381e-23; 

lambdaMin = 10e-9;
lambdaMax = 10e-6; 
nSteps = 1000000; 

dLambda = (lambdaMax - lambdaMin) / nSteps;

I = 0;

for i = 1:nSteps
    lambda = lambdaMin + (i-1) * dLambda;
    E = (2 * h * c^2) / (lambda^5 * ((exp(h * c / (lambda * k * T)) - 1)));
    I = I + E * dLambda;
end
```

Comment: It will be easier for us to help if you include the expression of the integral you want to evaluate, what the expected result of that integral is, and what specific problem you have with the loop

Comment: Numerical integration to infinity requires understanding convergence: to what value it converges (must be 0 of course) and how quickly. This allows you to divide the x axis up into segments in a way that minimizes errors when computing the integral numerically. I’m sure there are standard methods out there, did you Google for that?

Comment: Have you tied using the `integral` function?